# Why does this "Aux" pattern work for Shapeless but not for me?

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-macros

I am trying to generate a compile-time tuple type out of a case class.
I think, I am doing exactly the same thing shapeless does with generics:

```
class TupleProvider[T <: Product] {
  type Repr
  def provide(t: T): Repr = ???
}

object TupleProvider {
  type Aux[T <: Product, R] = TupleProvider[T] {type Repr = R}
  def apply[T <: Product](implicit tp: TupleProvider[T]): Aux[T, tp.Repr] = tp
  implicit def materialize[T, R]: Aux[T, R] = macro TypeProviderMacros.repr1[T, R]

  def instance[T <: Product, R <: Product]: Aux[T, R] = new TupleProvider[T] { type Repr = R }
}

class TypeProviderMacros(val c: whitebox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  def repr1[T: WeakTypeTag, R: WeakTypeTag] = {
    q"TupleProvider.instance[${weakTypeOf[T]}, ${typeOf[Tuple2[String, Int]]}]"
  }
}
```

However, if I do something like

```
case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)
val p = TupleProvider[Foo]
```

`p` ends up having type `TupleProvider.Aux[Foo, Nothing]`

I can't figure out what specifically am I doing differently from shapless.Generic, which seems to be implemented in exactly the same way, but gives me this:

```
val g: Aux[Foo, Int :: String :: HNil] = Generic[Foo]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shapeless uses whitebox macros to: 1) take _only 1_ type, 2) compute the other type (`Reps`) _inside_ a macro 3) return the value with computed type which is visible outside because it uses whitebox macros.

Comment: Your code depends on Scala's inference to guess the right `Repr` type, in such cases Scala often picks the first matching thing like `Nothing` or `Any`.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok yeah ... but the question is what specifically I am doing differently here. Yeah, my code depends on inference, but so does shapeless, I practically copied it, just changed the class names

Comment: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/9e2a2c87cc54577b91ce0e1869651a67cdb69141/core/shared/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic.scala#L943 - look at this code. It uses whitebox macros and only `T` has WeakTypeTag. Probably `R` would be inferred to `Nothing` or `Any` or sth like that. BUT since this is whitebox macro, macro can specialize the type in the returned value and this is probably where Nothing/Any is specialized to type computed inside a macro, not in inference.

Comment: Well, I am also using whitebox macros, and the shapeless version I was looking at had WeakTypeTag for both T, and R ... Anyway, I tried removing the type tag from R, nothing changed 

Comment: Yeah, this is where it is specialized `q"$generic.instance[$tpe, $repr]` 
I also do that: `q"TupleProvider.instance[${weakTypeOf[T]}, ${typeOf[Tuple2[String, Int]]}]"`

Comment: Have you tried printing and comparing the corresponding Exprs and ASTs?

Comment: *`p` ends up having type `TupleProvider.Aux[Foo, Nothing]`* What do you mean exactly by this? "ends up"? If you run repl you'll see that `p` has type `TupleProvider[Foo]{type Repr = (String, Int)}` so your code seems to work properly.

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/Zuug3ViyRpK63jEVpVZSYg

Comment: @DmytroMitin yeah, looks like `eval` does something differently :/ 
When I just try to write `val p:  TupleProvider.Aux[Foo, (String, Int)] = TupleProvider[Foo]` in actual code, it doesn't compile, complaining that it wanted (String, Int) but found Nothing :/

Comment: @Dima I used `eval` only because Scastie doesn't allow multi-project snippets. You can see the project at github: https://github.com/DmytroMitin/so77398294 https://github.com/DmytroMitin/so77398294/commit/1213cf02ac40a7a204e74cd7db3e768dabaef0ab The code compiles: https://github.com/DmytroMitin/so77398294/actions/runs/6772040689/job/18403735263